# Return list of dictionaries using django get_queryset()

Tags: django, python-3.x, mongodb, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am facing an error while trying to fetch and return data from database.

I am using `get_queryset()` returning queryset. command that i am using is `data = MyModel.objects.filter(account_id=account_id)` but i am getting error **'BaseList' object has no attribute 'items'**.

I think it is due to my data in the database, I have data in this format in my DB, is it due to result has list of dictionaries?

```
{
"result" : [ 
        {
            "savings" : 43.0548666420733,
            "count" : 18
        }, 
        {
            "savings" : 387.651510654053,
            "count" : 161
        }],
    }
```

**models.py**

```
from mongoengine import Document, fields


class MyModel(Document):
    result = fields.DictField()
```

**views.py**

```
class MyModelViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    renderer_classes = [renderers.JSONRenderer]
    serializer_class = MyModelSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        try:
            data = MyModel.objects.filter(account_id=self.kwargs['account_id'])
            return data
        except Exception as e:
            logger.exception(e)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.DocumentSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = MyModel
    fields = '__all__
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^account/(?P<account_id>\w+)/myviews',MyModelViewset.as_view({'get':'list'}))
```

Comment: post full error trackback

Comment: File "C:\Users\gsc-30310\PycharmProjects\AWS\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\fields.py", line 1683, in to_representation
    for key, val in value.items()
AttributeError: 'BaseList' object has no attribute 'items'

Comment: Could you post your full `MyModel`? It is missing the account_id in this case

Comment: hi @bagerard, I am passing account_id in url and fetching it using `account_id=self.kwargs['account_id']`.

Comment: sorry I forgot to add urls.py, I have added it now, also changed `filter method` in `views.py` to `filter(account_id=self.kwargs['account_id']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I suspected error was coming from the database.
I have changed this

```
    {
"result" : [ 
        {
            "savings" : 43.0548666420733,
            "count" : 18
        }, 
        {
            "savings" : 387.651510654053,
            "count" : 161
        }],
    }
```

to this

```
    {
"result" : {"data":[ 
        {
            "savings" : 43.0548666420733,
            "count" : 18
        }, 
        {
            "savings" : 387.651510654053,
            "count" : 161
        }]}
    }
```

and now everything is working fine.
**Basically, `result` was of type `array` and i have converted it to type `object`**